# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. trcToken public cwcTokenId = trcToken(1004777); ^------^

Tags: blockchain, solidity

pragma solidity 0.5.8;

contract CWC is ITokenDeposit {

```
using SafeMath for uint256;
string public name = "Decentralized CWC";
string public symbol = "CWC";
uint8  public decimals = 18;
trcToken  public usddTokenId = trcToken(1004777);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't include a definition of `trcToken`.

In order to solve the error, either import or create its definition. It can be an `interface` or a `contract`.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.8;

interface ITokenDeposit {}

interface trcToken {}

contract CWC is ITokenDeposit {
  //using SafeMath for uint256;
  string public name = "Decentralized CWC";
  string public symbol = "CWC";
  uint8  public decimals = 18;
  trcToken  public usddTokenId = trcToken(1004777);
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Member "tokenid" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in msg. require(msg.tokenid == usddTokenId, "deposit tokenId not USDD");

Comment: @Chetan There's no `tokenId` property of the global `msg` variable.